# IIS Performance issues moving from 7 to 8.5

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8.5

We are moving about 100 websites from a IIS 7 based solution to an IIS 8.5 solution.  Both are Load Balanced, and based around 2 shared Virtual Machines running IIS.

All the sites were running fine on the old solution, a page load taking anywhere from 0.2 to 2 seconds.  We upgraded to a supposed faster solution so that we had more room to expand and add more sites, but now the load is on the new solution we are having massive performance issues.  We have only started having issues once repointing about 40 of the sites to the new servers (and we didn't repoint the remaining sites).

After a site IIS reset or changing an app pool setting all the sites run nice and fast for about 10-20 minutes, but then hit a brick wall and requests intermittently take 10-20 times as long for any page on a site (but still return with no errors).  We have a mix of .NET 3.5 webforms and MVC .net 4.5 sites.  All sites are affected, but it seems to affect the MVC sites more frequently.

I think it's load related, but the CPU shows hardly anything (barely goes over 30%), ram is around 80% with 3GB free, and even if there is nothing else running on the server sites re still slow after the initial period.  It's like the app pools are blocking or running out of memory or something, but we can't see any actual blocks anywhere and it all seems random.

Things we've tried which don't make any difference after the 20 minute reset period:

- Bypassing Load balancer
- Checking differences between the new web servers (both have the same issue, but can have it at different times)
- Checked Perfmon, active threads count hovers between 0 and 5, sometimes spikes at 10, requests/sec peaks at 20.
- Increased MaxPoolThreads to 20 and MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU to 5000 as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377050%28v=bts.70%29.aspx (though hard to tell if that actually worked)
- Event viewer shows no unexpected app pool recycling
- changed worker processes to 4 (we have a session state server)
- occurs even when "%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list request" shows no blocking items, and appcmd can show blocking on .css and .jpg files as well as any web page (a small jpg can show response time of up to 60 seconds)
- Turned off file indexing for C drive and shared IIS files.
- Change session state back to InProc for sessions.
- FailedReqLogFiles on applications just show time taken of (for example) 2969ms but only significant time on breakdown is 719ms for VIRTUAL_MODULE_UNRESOLVED on FormsAuthentication

Other info
 - There are no memory limits of request limits on app pools, which recycle every day at 3am
 - One site was running fine, we added another new website/app pool and the previous site slowed down 20x and the new site also ran slowly.
 - Is there a limit to number of websites or app pools?  We are currently up to ID 109 on the websites, but some have been removed so there are about 90 sites on there, with about 40 of them actually running

Any ideas on what to do or where else to look would be greatly appreciated!  We are programmer by trade but we are lumbered with trying to sort this out as the host is saying it's not their problem!

Comment: You haven't said "where" the request gets 10-20x slower? Is it processing the request slower once it hits the server or is it taking that much longer to initiate the request, etc?? It's unlikely to be slower everywhere by some evenly distributed percentage. Starting with the "where" will lead to the "what". Right now it seems the entire pipeline is under suspicion which leads to checking everything which is waste of time. Need some measurements.

Comment: Also what sort of sites are these? Heavy CMS like sites hitting a DB with every request, lots of async?? If so is the DB server the same as before or has that changed too? Async is great for freeing up the web server but it can just as easily shift a bottleneck from web server to DB server. People sometimes forget that when "Increas[ing] MaxPoolThreads to 20 and MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU to 5000"

Comment: appcmd shows that the process is running slowly, so requests are getting to the server fine but blocking somewhere during processing.  The sites are heavy CMS sites hitting DB up to 30 times (though there is caching), but the DB hasn't changed and is not showing any signs of load either.  I'm trying to use windbg right now to find an actual deadlock [link](http://atombrenner.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/how-to-find-deadlocks-in-aspnet.html)

Comment: apparently there are no deadlocks :-(  Another dead end

Comment: Did you find the issue? We are experiencing same problems with moving from IIS 7 to IIS8.5 for several sites with the same code (different domains/databases only). Just one of them are getting hang somewhere during execution. Looks like same issue as you have had.